# jQuery UI, JavaScript, param and (maybe) closure

Tags: jquery-ui, closures

Here's my JavaScript sample:

```
  function createButtons(idDialog, tab, fn, param) {
    var btns = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
      btns.push( {
        text: (tab[i]>0 ? '+':'')+tab[i],
        click: function(a) {
          console.log(fn);
          console.log(param);
          fn(param);
          $(this).dialog("close");
        }
      });
    };
    btns.push( {
      text: "Close",
      click: function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    });
    $(idDialog).dialog('option', 'buttons', btns);
  }
```

The params: `fn` is a function that should be called whenever we click the button, and `param` is a param that should be *passed* to the function.

When I use this code, `console.log(fn)` says `undefined` and `console.log(param)` says `undefined`. It kinddof doesn't recall the param.

How should I do?

Comment: Maybe a jsFiddle would help us help you? http://jsfiddle.net/Jxt67/

Comment: @JoshNaro Including the jquery ui css seems to make the fiddle work: http://jsfiddle.net/Jxt67/2/. OP not sure why you're seeing undefined in the console.

Comment: I'm not sure what OP's call to createButtons looks like or the HTML. That's why I provided the fiddle for OP.

Comment: Josh, it works. My params were bad. May I ask you to answer with the fiddle as a code so I can check your answer as valid? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've asked JoshNaro to answer but he didn't so here's the solution he gave that works perfectly:

```
function createButtons(idDialog, tab, fn, param) {
    var btns = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
      btns.push( {
        text: (tab[i]>0 ? '+':'')+tab[i],
        click: function(a) {
          console.log(fn);
          console.log(param);
          fn(param);
          $(this).dialog("close");
        }
      });
    };
    btns.push( {
      text: "Close",
      click: function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    });
    $(idDialog).dialog('option', 'buttons', btns);
  }


createButtons(
    "#Hello",
    ['Save', 'Load'],
    function(parameter) {
        alert(parameter);
    },
    'World'
);
```